# look for specific node in XML multiple times and get the value of all the nodes

Tags: c#, sql, xml, visual-studio

My XML looks something like this. I have a node Status and this Status can be under random parent node and multiple times. But I want to search for each Status in my XML and capture the value say Approve in variable. How Can I do this? Also, Once I have collected all the Status ,I want them to be stored in Database. Basically, I want to look for all Status in my XML and capture those values.

```
            <loop1>
                <loop2>
                    <ID>001</ID>
                    <status code="A">approve</status>
                    </loop2>
                    </loop1>
```

Any help is appreciated!

I tried with below code -

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
              xDoc.LoadXml(xmlValue);--xmlValue has my XML file content
              XmlElement xelRoot = xDoc.DocumentElement;
              XmlNodeList xnlNodes = xelRoot.SelectNodes("/status");
         foreach (XmlNode xNode in xnlNodes)
              {
                  string ostatus = xNode["status"].InnerText;
              }
```

But I am getting error object reference not set an instance when I try to read innertext.

Comment: Did you tried something already? Can you show us some code?

Comment: Do you want to do this in C# application or should the database system solve this (which RDBMS - product and version)??? You might read about *deep search `XPath`* like `//status`...

Comment: I tried with XMLelement and XMLdocument, but When I try to extract status, it gives object reference not set to an instance error.I basically want to capture all the status Values, and then check in database if status isapproved, then bla bla else if status is deny then bla bla

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most elegant approach, but you are close:

*I added one more status node to the XML*

```
string YourXml = "<loop1><loop2><ID>001</ID><status code = \"A\">approve</status><status code = \"B\">deny</status></loop2></loop1>";

XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.LoadXml(YourXml); 
    XmlElement xelRoot = xDoc.DocumentElement;
XmlNodeList xnlNodes = xelRoot.SelectNodes("//status"); //Deep search!!
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (XmlNode xNode in xnlNodes) {
    sb.AppendLine( string.Format("code='{0}' value='{1}'", xNode.Attributes["code"].Value,xNode.InnerText));
}
string result = sb.ToString();
```

The result is

```
code = 'A' value = 'approve'
code = 'B' value = 'deny'
```